# How to merge object property types in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I found several similar questions on this topic but more around object property and not their type. Basically my question is simple:

```
type Params = StringParam | StringArrayParam
type StringParam = { [parameter: string]: string }
type StringArrayParam = { [parameter: string]: string[] }
const parameters: Params = { entry1: ['hi', 'hello'], entry2: 'hi there' }
```

I'm trying to get `Params` to become `{ [parameter: string]: string | string[] }` but neither `|` or `&` seem to work because they see `StringParam` and `StringArrayParam` as independent types.

Is there a way to actually merge the types so that the same property can have both `string | string[]` as a value or is my only option to define `type Params = { [parameter: string]: string | string[] }`

Comment: Your example is so small that I'd just "manually" define `Params` as `{ [parameter: string]: string | string[] }`. It's longer (and more effort) to write a type to transform `StringParam` and `StringArrayParam` into the desired type.

Comment: Yeah this is just an example, but I was curious if there was a way to do this for a more complex case? Seeing how complex it would be for this simple case would help

Comment: Yes, you can see, my answer. We can use Parameter TS Utility when defining the merged interface type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 type Params = {
    [Property in keyof StringParam]: string | StringArrayParam[Property];
  }
  type StringParam = { [parameter: string]: string }
  type StringArrayParam = { [parameter: string]: string[] }

  const parameters: Params = { entry1: ['hi', 'hello'], entry2: 'hi there' }
  
  console.log(parameters);
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwM5QLxQN4CgpQDaMCA9pAqFAJYB2UA1hCKQGZQDKwCdA5vEmQBdAFxRU3PlAA%20nSbV4BBBEhACUxMhVBCA3LgC%20uUJDk8F65JhxEwiFBGAQEYied6jx83lCMnoXO7KqpbW2Lb2yI7Ort6ebnyEQr64uADGpLQSUHaC0QioYpboWOEQtNwgAIxihADkABbUdQA0UI0QADadpHVCbeWVAExijdRQwA3OEHW%20QA)